# How can I let the source code appear in Maven's internal repository in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

After building a Maven internal repository and linking it to eclipse I was able to see the repository by going to `Window -> Show View -> Other -> Maven -> Maven Repositories`. The repositories appeared in Eclipse but I can only see the .jar and .war files in them. The java source codes, js files, css... can't seem to appear in Maven Repositories in Eclipse although the repository contains such files. Any idea on how can I let them appear?

The "download artifacts sources" and the "download artifact javadocs" are already checked in my Eclipse.

Comment: Do you see the `-sources.jar` packages in your repository for your Java classes? It could also possible that there are no sources packages in Central for the appropriate libs.

Comment: No I can't see the -sources.jar packages. How can I add them?